# Adding Disqus to multiple [All] pages on Github domain

Tags: disqus, github-pages

I have managed to correctly set up Disqus [for one of my](http://avi-aryan.github.io/Autohotkey.html) Github pages, thanks to this helpful [article](http://erjjones.github.io/blog/How-I-built-my-blog-in-one-day/).
Now I would like to ask if is there a way to add this Disqus integration to all my pages [on the domain](https://github.com/avi-aryan/avi-aryan.github.com).

**P.S.** - I have a footer.html which is `<iframe>`d in all my github pages. Is there something I can use from that to help my purpose. There are many sites that have disqus on all there pages, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I do understand, you want to add a disqus input for each article of your blog.
Well, Jekyll use the liquid templating language, that allow html includes.

I defined a layout in '**_layout**' directory (e.g: default.html). I put a front-matter inside this file to tell Jekyll that I want to parse this file when I run 'jekyll build'.

I also create a disqus.html (in my **_include** directory) where i paste the disqus snippet of code they provide me with.
I include this snippet in the default layout (where ever you want). {% include disqus.html %} (I do not use literal name like toto.html but rather variable. But it doesn't matter. We can do so)

And in each blog posts, in **_post** directory, in the front-matter I define 'layout: default'

That said, if you don't have the Jekyll documentation in mind, my exlpanation would be 
harsh to understand. So feel free to check my blog source... and the manual :).

http://ihommani.github.io/

Cheer

Comment: I never tried to learn more about Jekyll. I looked at the docs now and it looks like it can do my job. Thanks, your source also helps as it is a working example. I will use it to start my tests. One question... is jekyll includes google SEO friendly ? What if my use jekyll to include all my page content from a static HTML content stored in Dropbox. Will the jekyll link show correctly in google searches ?

Comment: Hi, well concerning googleAnalitycs i don't know. I'm not yet an SEO master :). As far as i understand Jekyll, there is no specific integration tools for SEO. For disqus either for that matter.It's just other lines to paste in your layouts from the SEO documentations. Concerning your need to store your HTML in dropbox, I don't get it since you use githubPages. But you surely do have a reason. But again I don't know. Concerning my blog i switched today from Jekyll to Pelican. It's more consistent and the separation of concern is great. The integration with Disqus and co is smoother.

Answer (score 1):

As chaiyachaiya already mentioned, using Disqus in Jekyll is really simple. You simply put this code whereever you want the comment thread to appear:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = '{{ site.disqus_shortname }}'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
    }());
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Simply edit {{ site.disqus_shortname }}, or you can specify it in your site's _config.yml file

Answer (score 0):

I there,

Like i said I swithed from Jekyll to Pelican. 
Pelican already embed all the stuff you need to integrate Disqus or google analytics in your blog. 
All you need is to specify your disqus domain in the pelicanconf file.

No manual work anymore! And like i said it's the same for google analytics.

The switching part for you may not be so hard. All you need is to tranfer your article i guess . There's little work to publish the pelican blog on gh-pages. (so little).
I encourage you to take a look at the tool. It worth it.

http://blog.getpelican.com/